# Tensorflow2 object-detection training | To make the test results the same

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I'm a developer who is studying Tensorflow object-detection.

I'm training through this config file, and **even if the training environment is all the same**, the test results (detection) are different. And the training course follows the link below.

> Config file : [faster_rcnn_resnet50_v1_800x1333_coco17_gpu-8.config](http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/tf2/20200711/faster_rcnn_resnet50_v1_800x1333_coco17_gpu-8.tar.gz)
>
> Reference : [Tensorflow2 object-detection](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html)

I'd like to **make the test results the same**, what's the way?

Comment: Is it a problem that no one can solve?